# Stretch width of UILabel according to width of containing text with background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have the following problem - I need to create two UI labels along side one another as in the screen shot below -

[image]

The UI label containing the special offers text is dynamic and needs to adjust to the width of the containing text and also if possible display the slanted orange background with the relevant padding -

I'm predominantly a Front-end dev - so with CSS i'd use a long background image that aligns to the right of the label and pad accordingly - but I have no idea how to approach this in objective C - can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a drop-in solution, but perhaps helps you find it (assuming you don't use Auto Layout):

- You need a `UIImageView` for the background and a `UILabel` for the text
- Use a tileable/strechable image (probably with cap insets) for the background (see [`[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3aresizingMode%3a))
- Set the text on your label
- Call `[label sizeToFit]` to resize the label to exactly fit the contained text
- Resize the image view depending on the label's size (e.g. `imageView.frame = CGRectInset(label.frame, -10, -10)`, which would make your image view 10pt larger than the label on all sides).

With Auto Layout you'd just define the appropriate constraints between the label and the image view and rely on the label's "intrinsic content size" - should be quite easy.

Answer (score 1):

You could always shrink the text when it gets to long for the label, go into your view controller, click on the label that you would like to shrink when the text gets too long, then, go down to Autoshrink under Label in the attributes inspector. Change it from fixed font size to minimum font size, then I recommend putting 6 to 8 as the lowest font size. This is going to be the LOWEST font size though, so if XCode can make the label fit while making the font size 9, yet the lowest is 7, it will do it.

Or, you could get the length of the string with

```
int *stringLength = [myString length]
```

which counts spaces too, then, change the orange square with

```
orangeBoxImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, resizedWidth, resizedHeight);
```

so you could do something like this with your code:

```
if(stringLength == 15{
    orangeBoxImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 5);
}
```

Comment: The question is about sizing the background image correctly, rather than adjusting the label's font size automatically to fit.

Comment: @DanielRinser I know. I'll see if I can find anything else online. Just thought you would like to know because at the time I posted this you had no other answers. It is true though, that you could always get the length of the string and then manipulate the orange box based upon that. Look in my updated answer for how to do that

Comment: First, I think you misunderstood that I'm not the one who asked the question.. ;) Regarding your answer: No, no, no.. Almost all fonts have a variable char width (simply put: an "m" is larger than an "i"). So, simply using the strings length (== number of chars) to calculate it's rendered size is not good at all. See the other answers for ways to calculate the size of the rendered string.

Comment: @DanielRinser i know you weren't the one who asked... Also using `==` is just an example, you would never want to do that

Answer (score 1):

I hope this could help you

```
CGFloat rect = [YOURSTRING
    boundingRectWithSize: (CGSize){ labelWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX }
    options: NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
    attributes: @{ NSFontAttributeName : labelFont };
    context: nil];
```

This assumes numberOfLines = 0.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is `UILabel -sizeToFit` inherited from `UIView`. You should be able to figure out the rest from there.

Answer (score 0):

Find the size of the containing text with

```
[text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, height) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakModexx]
```

Once you have that, you can manipulate the size of the label accordingly.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For the background I'd create a subclass of UILabel that overrides drawInRect:, such as this example that simply draws a rectangle with the size of the label

```
-(void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {  

    [super drawRect:rect];  
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
```

Rather than drawing a rectangle, you should create a path with the shape that you need and fill that. See here for more info:

http://weblog.invasivecode.com/core-graphics

I don't know how you've created your label, but if it's done properly with autolayout it'll have the correct width automagically. See here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/

Tim